# Nested attributes in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I'm trying to create a rake task to populate my DB. I need to to create  1 user with a specifc set of deatails and 99 other randomly genraterated . The details that are required are for two Models at the same time, similar to a form with nested attribues. My model uses an after_create call back to create and link a users to a team. The team name by default is the users name

the current code that I have used it producing errors

sample_data.rake

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
  user = User.create!(:profile_attributes => { name: Forgery::Name.full_name },
              email: "test@example.com",
              password: "123qwe",
              password_confirmation: "123qwe")
  99.times do |n|
      :profile_attributes => { name: Forgery::Name.full_name },
      email = Forgery::Internet.email_address
      password  = "password"
      user = User.create!(email: email,
                          password: password,
                          password_confirmation: password)
     end 
  end
end
```

Model that relys on the nested attibute.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :set_user_on_team



  private
  def set_user_on_team
     self.create_owned_team(:name => self.profile.name ).users << self

  end

end
```

error message

```
rake aborted!
/lib/tasks/sample_date.rake:9: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting keyword_end
    :profile_attributes => { name:  Forgery::Name.full_name },
                        ^
/lib/tasks/sample_date.rake:9: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
```

Comment: I have update the question to include the error message. the included rake file is my current attempt

Comment: Probably, you should remove line 9 `:profile_attributes => { name: Forgery::Name.full_name },`, add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile`, declare model relations `has_one :profile`. Also, I advise you to use consistent hash style (old or new) in entire application.

Comment: They association are included in my code I just removed them to make the callback clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed some syntax errors in the `99.times` block. You could try it like this:

```
99.times do |n|
  profile_attributes = { name: Forgery::Name.full_name }
  email = Forgery::Internet.email_address
  password  = "password"
  user = User.create!(profile_attributes: profile_attributes, #my assumption
                      email: email,
                      password: password,
                      password_confirmation: password)
end
```